# "can drive" or "drive"

Tags: modal-verbs, present-simple

> can (modal verb): to be able to. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can)

In the following two statements she able to drive. So, What is the difference in meaning between them?

> 1. She **can drive** motorcycle.
> 2. She **drives** motorcycle.

Is second one used when the speaker is more confident about the information?

Comment: _Drive**s**_ and I'd say it demands a context in which _drives_ is interchangeable with _can drive_. "She won't even ride a pony." "Oh really? I'd like to see your face when you know she drives a motorcyle." We use simple present to say what someone generally does we don't mean to emphasise the ability to something e.g. _he drives a bus_ means _he's a bus driver_ we don't really want to imply he can drive a bus. The context again can be really helpful.

Comment: The latter just simply state **the fact** that she drives a motorcycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> She can drive a motorcycle.

This means that she is able to drive a motorcycle, or that she has permission to do so.

> She drives a motorcycle.

Usage of present simple in this way indicates a habitual action, like "she smokes". Depending on the context, it could mean that she prefers to get about on a motorbike, rather than a car, or (if the listener had asked what she did for a living) that she is a motorcycle courier.

Note that  most English speakers would use the verb **ride** for a motorcycle, rather than **drive**. Also note that you need an indefinite article **a** before  **motorcycle**, because it is the singular of a countable noun.